# How do I set initial supply for a ERC-1155?

Tags: truffle, openzeppelin-contracts, ganache-cli, erc-1155, mint

In my smart contract I set 2 different token types:

```
uint256 public constant COIN = 0;
uint256 public constant OBJECT_NFT = 1;
```

And my **constructor** has the initial mint for a specific address, but when I try to consult the balance of that address, it does not show the new supply...

```
constructor() ERC1155("https://myawsomegame.com/token-data-{id}.html") {
        _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _setupRole(URI_SETTER_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _setupRole(MINTER_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _mint(msg.sender, COIN, 500000000, "");
    }
```

Comment: not sure where you are getting that mint function from? are you importing anything?
Mint usually take an amount and a destination You are minting to msg.sender. what is the 0 what is the 5000000000 ?

Comment: It is based in an ERC-1155 smart contract from OpenZeppelin, look at this link: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc1155